# create joint to fix body to another body with box2d

Tags: javascript, html, box2d

I want to create a catapult fixed to the ground  beacause i will rotate it later using mouse joint  this is my code to fix catapult_arm to the ground

{

var revJointDef = new Box2D.Dynamics.Joints.b2RevoluteJointDef;

```
revJointDef.Initialize(ground,catapult,b2Vec2(catapult_height,ground_height));  

revJointDef.enableMotor = true;    

revJointDef.enableLimit = true;   

revJointDef.motorSpeed  = -1260;    

revJointDef.lowerAngle  = 0.15;    

revJointDef.upperAngle  = 1.30;   

revJointDef.maxMotorTorque = 4800;
```

the problam is the hinge point , I think b2Vec2(catapult_height,ground_height) is false  , what should I put as params ?

Comment: What problem do you get with this arrangement?